# Сделать общую сумму в GridView Yii2 с учётом фильтров

Tags: yii2

Необходимо в GridView в футере выводить сумму значений определенных столбцов в формате: `Сумма значений столбцов в GridView/Общая сумма значений.`

> Пример:
>   У нас есть столбец "Просмотры". Всего 5 записей, суммарно их кол-во просмотров - 1000.В GridView 2 записи, в сумме у них просмотров - 200.
>   На выходе имеем: **200/1000**

Сумма значений столбцов в GridView - **реализована**.
**Задача**: Остаётся вывод общей суммы значений, но чтобы применимы были фильтры.

> Пример:
>   У нас два столбца "Views" и "Country". Записи:
>   1. V: 100, C: RU.
>   2. V: 100, C: RU.
>   3. V: 100, C: RU.
>   4. V: 200, C: USA.
>
> В GridView, 2 записи(1, 2), включен фильтр Country=RU. Итоговое число:
>   **200/300**. Если бы фильтр не был бы включен, итог: **200/500**.

Каким образом этого можно добиться? По-сути, необходимо как-то подхватывать фильтры searchModel'и, либо проводить подсчёт в ней.

---

Также приложу реализацию суммы значений столбцов GridView:

```
class NumberColumn extends DataColumn
{
    private $total = 0;

    public function getDataCellValue($model, $key, $index)
    {
        $value = parent::getDataCellValue($model, $key, $index);
        $this->total += $value;
        return $value;
    }

    protected function renderFooterCellContent()
    {
        return $this->grid->formatter->format($this->total, $this->format);
    }
}
```

Ячейка в columns GV:

```
[
   'class' => \app\components\NumberColumn::class,
    'attribute' => 'views',
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected function renderFooterCellContent()
{
    return $this->grid->formatter->format($this->total, $this->format)
        . '/' . $this->grid->dataProvider->query->sum('views');
}
```